rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyUSB0 error while running this file
File "/home/tilak/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rosserial_python/serial_node.py", line 15, in <module>
    exec(compile(fh.read(), python_script, 'exec'), context)
  File "/home/tilak/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rosserial_python/serial_node.py", line 15, in <module>
    exec(compile(fh.read(), python_script, 'exec'), context)
  File "/home/tilak/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rosserial_python/serial_node.py", line 15, in <module>
    exec(compile(fh.read(), python_script, 'exec'), context)
  File "/home/tilak/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rosserial_python/serial_node.py", line 15, in <module>
    exec(compile(fh.read(), python_script, 'exec'), context)
  File "/home/tilak/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rosserial_python/serial_node.py", line 7, in <module>
    with open(python_script, 'r') as fh:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
tilak@tilak-Lenovo-ideapad-330S-14IKB:~$ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyUSB0 

i was just trying to use rosserial and this error is constantly coming while trying to use esp32 with rosserial

It looks like you built from source. What repo and branch are you using?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
